# get all controls of a type and change their properties

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, controls

in my software I have a `TabControl` and I want to search for all `Controls` of a certain type using `foreach` (for example) and change some of there properties.
Now when I do something like this:

```
Control ctrl;
ctrl = My_CheckedListBox;
((CheckedListBox)ctrl).SetItemChecked(0, false);
```

It works fine and the checkboxes all get unchecked, no problem. But when I use foreach they don't:

```
foreach (Control item in ModuleTab.Controls)
    {
      if (item is CheckedListBox)
          {
             for (int i = 0; i < ((CheckedListBox)item).Items.Count; i++)
                {
                   ((CheckedListBox)item).SetItemChecked(i, false);
                }    
          }
    }
```

I know it is because `item` is not really the `Control` but an object. I wonder if there is something like:

```
foreach (Control ref item in ModuleTab.Controls)
```

Any help?

Comment: No, I think you've misdiagnosed the problem - and misunderstood what `ref` means at the same time. (See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) It's not like `foreach` is copying the objects. What are you actually *observing*? Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? (As a readability hint: your code would be a lot cleaner if you just used `as`, or cast *once* storing the result as a local variable within your `if` statement.)

Comment: The problem is that I want to find all `CheckedListBox` controls and uncheck all the checkBoxes in them. Believe me I used as before posting this but `as`  also copies the object as I think. 
And: If I "store the result as a local variable" as u suggest I would also copy the control and won't be able to change a property of it.

Comment: That doesn't tell us what you've observed, nor does it give us an example we can use to reproduce the problem for ourselves. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: I don't really follow what do you mean with "observe" here!

Comment: What you've seen when you've run this code, compared with what you expected to see. "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us that.

Comment: Really? Ok I thought it was clear. I'll edit the post accordingly..

Comment: @JonSkeet I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Well you haven't explained whether *anything* happens, or what you've done to diagnose the problem - have you stepped through the code with a debugger? Do you get into the `foreach` loop? Do you get into your `if` statement? Do you get into your `for` loop? My guess is that the control you're looking for isn't in `ModuleTab.Controls`, but we can't tell with so little information. Again, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem (it's easy to write a trivial WinForms app with no designer in less than 50 lines of code) would go a long way towards helping us help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet please take a look at the answer..

Comment: I don't think so. And I'll not delete any question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it! Jon Skeet was right. The Tab in the `TabControl` didn't contain the controls I was looking for because they were all in a `GroupBox`!
I searched for them in the `GroupBox` and there they were. The `CheckBoxes` where unchecked and everything worked perfectly as it should.

@Jon Thx for the "observing" tip. I let the program show me the available `Controls` in the Tab using a `MessageBox` and that is how I solved it. Thx also for the user who deleted his answer because he interduced me to the `OfType<>()` method.That really made the code look better:

```
foreach (var groupbox in ModuleTab.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
            {
                foreach (var item in groupbox.Controls.OfType<CheckedListBox>())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        item.SetItemChecked(i, false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control item in ModuleTab.Controls)
{
  if (item.GetType() == typeof(CheckedListBox)))
   {
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Items.Count; i++)
        {
         item.SetItemChecked(i, false);
        }
   }
}
```